# Developing Java (Maven) application on Docker container

Tags: java, maven, docker, intellij-idea

For a new Spring project I'd like to setup a Docker container to build + run + debug my application.

At the moment I'm using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.2-jdk-8-slim
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN mvn clean package

FROM maven:3.6.2-jdk-8-slim
COPY target/app.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005", "-jar","/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 5005
```

In the first step the project is built. In the second step the application is run exposing a 5005 port for "remote" debugging.

Then from my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) I'm configuring a remote debugging configuration to execute debug on the container.

As you may guess is a bit awkward to execute these steps for every little edit I'd like to debug in the project.

So, I'm wondering if there's a more practical approach using IntelliJ to automatically build and attach the debugger to my application just like when developing directly on my dev machine...

Comment: Why can't you build the application locally during development? IntelliJ comes with bundled Maven as far as I remember, you don't even have to install stuff.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Sorry, I'm not an expert about Docker, so my doubt is: what's the real advantage of using a container if I'm going to develop my application locally (as usual) and deploy on Docker only after that?

Comment: When you go to deploy, you don't have to manually provision a JVM, or separately push a jar file around, because that's "baked in" to the image; the mechanics of launching the container and configuring its network ports are common across all Docker-based setups regardless of underlying languages; ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can open a `pom.xml` right from IntelliJ and run the application without the need to run maven (IntelliJ has an excellent maven plugin).

Since you're running it as a `java -jar` you don't even need an ultimate version of IntelliJ.

Now this is how we develop usually, even before maven. You can run `mvn clean package` locally as well if you want to, say, check that the tests are run (again, you can also do that in Idea). And when you push your changes create a docker and deploy on server.

This is by far the best solution I can recommend. The way you've described in the question suites more to debugging the remote servers (read ready environments).

If you absolutely need this way, you still can use HotSwap feature of JVM for small changes (as longs as these changes are inside the method): While connected via Remote Debugger, right click and "Recompile" the class that has a change. It will be automatically loaded to remote JVM so that you don't actually need to trigger all this process.

You also don't have to run all the tests in maven (`mvn clean package -Dmaven.tests.skip`)

Comment: Thank you. I'm not an expert about Docker, so my doubt is: what's the real advantage of using a container if I'm going to develop my application locally (as usual) and deploy on Docker only after that? Isn't it meant to "port your dev machine in production"?

Comment: No, docker is meant to provide the same way to deploy artifacts to environments (for example production) by means of containers. This way you don't need to care whether its a java application, python application, node app or anything else. It makes life much easier. The containers are isolated network and FS wise. It has nothing to do with local development. So there is no any advantage of using docker, only issues :) Use the right tool for the right job...

Comment: Now, sometimes if people run many services, it might make sense to run containers of other parts of the applications (like in microservices architecture) or databases locally (docker runs on windows, linux, macos) just to avoid connecting the service that you develop to real environment. But again, its not for running your own service that you develop... Hope it makes things more clear

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas that you can implement:

1. Use CI/CD to build your docker images

Instead of offloading this work to docker files, let your CI/CD pipeline to build your artifact and then pack it into a docker image ( you'll have more control over the process ). Finally, you can also deploy it to a targeted environment.

2. Use IntelliJ to run and debug your project on the DEV machine

You gain almost no benefit by running your project using Docker on your DEV machine, only a lot of hassle.